# Volume UP long press + new activity

Tags: android

in Activity A

```
@Override       
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
            int action = event.getAction();
            int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();

                switch (keyCode) {
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:

                    if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP&&event.isLongPress()==false) {
                        //navigate up
                    }
                    if(event.isLongPress()==true)
                         //start new activity B
                        startActivity(new Intent("com.example.fittle.FISH"));
                    return true;

                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
                    if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                        //navigate down
                       }
                    return true;
                default:
                    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
               }
            }
```

In Activity B

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    int action = event.getAction();
    int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();

        switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:

            if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP&&event.isLongPress()==false) {
                //navigate up
            }
            if(event.isLongPress()==true)
                //play sound
            return true;

        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
            if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                //navigate down
               }
            return true;
                if(event.isLongPress()==true)
                //go to activity A
        default:
            return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
       }


    }
```

I have two activities A and B. 
In activity A> i use the volume up/down keys to navigate through the various buttons and then long press up button to start an activity B.

When the activity B starts the volume goes up automatically.

I know it is happening because the long press is detected in the new activity B and then is treated as a short press to up the volume.

Is there a way to kill the detection of the previous long press in the new activity B

Comment: post some code as to what you are really doing.

Answer (score 0):

In activity B.

```
@Override
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
     // my logic when key is pressed in Activity b
 }
```

Comment: Tried this. The problem is that i want to navigate in the Activity B also through the use of the Volume up/down. So i have navigation codes in the onKeyDown method that runs the codes inside this method automatically.